# why is my chaine.charAT not a function and what else is broken in here

Tags: javascript, html

```
function chainePair(chaine) {
    var longueur = chaine.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= longueur; i += 2) {
        var result = chaine.charAT(i);
        document.getElementById("reponse1").innerHTML = result + " ";
    }
}​
```

I am trying to make this function write every 2 letter of my string in the space allocated by reponse1 id. example: the string monster would show: `m n t r`

Comment: `charAt` not `charAT` -- case matters

Comment: chaine is identified in my html properly with a document.form1.chaine.value that takes the text that the person writes in the text box

Comment: It also should be `i < longeur` not `<=`.  You will overrun your char array this way

Comment: You could also just use `chaine[i]`

Comment: @NullUserException `"abc".charAt(3)` returns the empty string; `"abc"[3]` returns `undefined`.

Comment: also use `innerHTML +=` instead of `innerHTML  =` or you'll overwrite previous writes.

Comment: @JanDvorak I guess; but it's not my fault if you fail to check your bounds.

Comment: @NullUserException Javascript does not have undefined behavior. You can do whatever you want, even `while(c=str.charAt(i++))`. Sure, `while(c=str[i++])` works just as well. But sometimes...

Comment: What about `chaine.replace(/(.)./g,"$1")`?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is case sensitive, use `.charAt()` method:

```
// ----------------------v
var result = chaine.charAt(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function chainePair(string){
    var result = "";
    for(var i=0; i<string.length; i+=2){
       result += string[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("response1").innerHTML = result+" ";
}
```

Comment: All this does is add spaces in between characters.